# Send Password with Several Special Characters as an Argument to SFTP Expect Script

Tags: bash, sftp, expect

I have a bash script that I want to use to kick off an expect script and send a password over to it using an argument.

The problem is that my password has several special characters and I am having a really hard time escaping them whenever I send them from bash over to expect.

If I pass over a password without special characters, it works.
However this password complexity is required.
I have tried multiple methods to escape the special characters, and have Googled this problem to death without success.  I have tried escaping with backslashes and also substituting the special characters with their hexadecimal values, and have tried a wide array of various bracketing and quoting in both scripts.

Here is the Bash script that calls the Expect script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
currentDate=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
DATE=$currentDate
expect_script=message_ftp
password="Pass\[word&"
zip_file="file.zip"
/mydir/$expect_script "$currentDate/$zip_file" "$DATE" "$password"
```

Here is the expect script called:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --
set timeout 300
set file1e "[lindex $argv 0 ]"
set today "[lindex $argv 1 ]"
set password "[lindex $argv 2 ]"
#set password ="Pass\[word&"  ***--If I uncomment this and comment out the line above, it works!***
set ip "sftp_User\@ftpServer"

spawn /bin/csh -f

send "/usr/bin/$ip\n"
expect "password*: "
send  "$password\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "mget $file1e\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "pwd\r"
expect "sftp>"

send "lpwd\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "quit\r"
sleep 10

exit 0
```

===========================================================================

***As far as security concerns (since I bet someone will ask):***
The eventual goal is to get the password from an external password utility from the bash script (can be done in the future; but is outside the scope of the current question), then send it over to the expect script. In the end, nothing will be plain text, as it is now. However, I need to get this working first as a proof of concept before I can go to the next step.

Thank you (in advance) to everyone who tries to help out.

Comment: Can you send the password base64 encoded?

Comment: I cannot for security reasons.  But the example provided should get us close enough.  Thanks Cole

Comment: I am looking at it now.  Will update shortly.

Comment: Could you `bash -x` your shell script and `expect -d` your expect script?

Comment: Yes Emily I will try that and will report back.